# Weird network issue

Tags: networking, isp

I just had a very strange experience. I could not open any internet connections, but pings worked fine and existing connections continued working as if nothing had happened.

I know nothing about the ISP-side of networking. Any idea what could cause this? It's working again now, so i'm really just curious.

EDIT: Pings to domain names and IP addresses worked. At the same time that I got ping replies from 216.58.207.238 (Google), running "telnet 216.58.207.238 80" gave me no route to host.

I had Transmission running and it kept both downloads and uploads as if nothing had happened. Perhaps it uses UDP for those transfers? I don't know.

But why would I get no route to host for a telnet connection when I got replies to my pings? I mean, shouldn't there either be a route to the host or not?

Comment: Do a DNS reset / flush. We do not know the details of your devices.

Comment: did you ping an IP or a domain name?

Comment: Both and both works.

Comment: Could you clarify - both work now, or both worked during the time your experience happened? It's better to update the question to new info than answer in a comment so the relevant details are easily available for community members who want to pitch in.

Comment: @Peregrino69: Thanks, yes, I added more details. Pings to both IP and domain name worked fine all along. Telnet gave no route to host.

Comment: OK that invalidated my answer so I deleted it. Weird indeed :-)